# Exception in apache http client

Tags: java

i m using eclipse ide and when i run my program everything works fine but when i run the same program on server then it gives me this exception and i have already put my all far files as well as in  my lib folder, Please help me to short out to this problem.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpRequest
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2836)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.controller.KeyRank.doPost(KeyRank.java:41)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is my code :

```
   public String readGoogle(String keyword, int page) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  

        // Create a method instance
        keyword = keyword.trim();
        keyword = keyword.replaceAll(" ", "+");

        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+keyword+"&start="+page+"&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=";
        String responseBody = "";
        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);  

        //Provide custom retry handler is necessary  
        //:OC:method.getParams().setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(3, false));  


        try{  
        //execute the method  


            System.out.println("executing request " + method.getURI());  

            // Create a response handler  
            ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
            responseBody = client.execute(method, responseHandler);  
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");  
            System.out.println(responseBody);  
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");  



            } catch (HTTPException e) {  

                    System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());  
                    e.printStackTrace();  

                } catch (IOException e) {  

                    System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                } finally {  

                    //release the connection  
              method.releaseConnection();  

        }
        return responseBody;

    }
```

Comment: ClassNotFoundException can only mean that the specified class is not on your classpath. Check again that all the right jars are on your classpath.

Comment: yes i have already added all my jars as well as i have added jar to my WEB-INF/lib folder (httpclient-4.2.3.jar) but it's giving me exception same code working when i run it using main. but not working when i run it on localhost

Comment: @ashishchaudharyjavaoracle You need httpcore jar file. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Add Http core jar to your build path, find the required jar from this url. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpcorejar.htm

deploy the jar and then compile, your error will be resolved.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Without your `classpath configuration` and knowledge about the web server you are deploying your application to, it is not easy to help but from the look of things, it seems you are missing the `HttpCore` jar in your deployment environment.

The missing class is found in that jar.